# how to create a simple passcode or password for a yet to be release website

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a website that I would like to keep hidden until we're ready to go live.

Is there a simple way to prompt for a passcode before the site is displayed. The purpose is not to stop hacker - but the users who login from phones/ipads etc.

I would like to support multiple passcodes if possible. I can send the link and the passcode together - until we're the site is full.

I researched and saw old php frameworks from 2000 etc. the site uses jquery - so I hoping for some simple suggestions that I can implement

thx

Comment: Client-side protection will not help, as it is defeated by simply disabling javascript. That said, I'd recommend simple Basic Authentication on your webserver. (for apache httpd:) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Comment: What are you using to build your site? Are you using any server side languages?

Comment: it's a basic one page launch page using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file to do this, have a look in this article [here](http://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator)

Comment: thanks - I am looking for passcode - and not a user/password combo. sorry if I was not clearer.

Comment: maybe this can help? [article stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444428/php-password-protected-website)